# Обновление клиентского ПО. Unity, C#, JSON

Tags: c#, json, unity3d, обновление

Доброго дня. Разрабатываем проект на движке Unity3D (версия 5.6.3f1), язык - C#, СУБД - Robomongo.
Сам по себе проект связан с обучением, можно сказать огромный сборник тестов и практических задач. Информация хранится в множестве различных справочников (таблиц), в виде JSON файлов. Многие справочники связаны между собой через первичный ключ. Ниже пример простого справочника: 
`[
        {
            "_id": "59630d659fbd0b28e8aa04fa",
            "Name": "Ответ1",
            "IsRight": true
        },
            "_id": "59630d659fbd0b28e8aa04fb",
            "Name": "Ответ2",
            "IsRight": false
        },
            "_id": "59630d659fbd0b28e8aa04fc",
            "Name": "Ответ3",
            "IsRight": false
        }
]`

И таких справочников порядка 90, в некоторых более 1000 строк.
Сейчас стоит вопрос с обновлением базы этих тестов на стороне пользователя. Допустим, у пользователя уже есть эта программа и база тестов, которая отдается изначально. Потом, когда мы выпускаем обновление, нужно, чтобы те справочники, которые уже были, обновились, либо не изменялись, в зависимости от того, меняли мы их или нет, а те, которых не было, добавились.
Пока, кроме объединения всех справочников в один большой справочник и дальнейшего сравнивания его с другим большим справочником, либо сравнения каждого справочника по отдельности, ничего на ум не приходит.

Подскажите пожалуйста, кто уже сталкивался с подобной задачей? Как добавить в клиентское ПО новые данные?

Comment: Для каждого справочника нужно добавить строковое значение в которое сохраняется версия этого справочника. Во время обновления считываем это значение и если оно старше (например 1.2, а новое 1.3), то заменяем его новым справочником.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну это типичная задача и решение для неё придумано тоже - типичное.

1. На главном сервере есть файл из двух колонок: в первой колонке имя файла  справочника, во второй - контрольная сумма этого файла.
2. Когда на клиенте запускается программа обновления, она считывает этот индексный файл с сервера.
3. Сравнивает только что полученный индекс с локальным.
4. Если локального индекса нет - скачиваются все справочники
5. Если локальный индекс есть он построчно сравнивается с новым
6. Если для очередной строки имя файла и контрольная сумма совпадают - строка пропускается
7. Если имя файла совпадает, а контрольная сумма нет - файл справочника обновляется
8. Если файла с таким именем нет - справочник скачивается

После завершения цикла по строкам индексного файла, старый индекс заменяется новым.